# Using procmail to forward inline

Tags: procmail

I would like to use procmail to forward a message to another email address.  Both the headers and body of the incoming message should be in the body of the outgoing message (inline forwarding).

Example incoming message:

```
From: outside@example.com
To: me@example.com
Subject: Test
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 05:00:04 GMT

This is a test
```

The forwarded message should be like this:

```
From: me@example.com
To: thirdparty@example.com
Subject: Fwd: Test
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 05:01:00 GMT

From: outside@example.com
To: me@example.com
Subject: Test
Date: Mon, 03 Nov 2014 05:00:04 GMT

This is a test
```

Can this be done using procmail, maybe in conjunction with something like formail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy enough.

```
:0
* Some conditions, perhaps?  Omit this line to forward unconditionally
* ^Subject:[    ]*\/.*
| (echo From: me@example.com; echo To: thirdparty@example.com; \
   echo "Subject: Fwd: $MATCH"; echo; cat -) | $SENDMAIL -t
```

If you don't care about forwarding the original Subject header verbatim, this can be simplified additionally.

The `-t` flag to `sendmail` says to use whatever `To:` and `Cc:` headers are in the message to determine the recipient.  I omitted generating a `Date:` because (most imitations of) Sendmail will do that for you.

The stuff in the square brackets should be one space and one tab, as usual.

If you want to keep a copy, either add `Bcc: yourself` (and take care to not have the incoming copy trigger a mail loop!) or change `:0` to `:0c` which makes Procmail continue down the rest if the recipe file.

Comment: The subject isn't important, so I can indeed simplify that bit.  This works great, thank you.

Comment: how do you add "Bcc:" yourself?

Comment: @Michael See now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50634411/how-to-make-procmail-forward-and-bcc-too though in here, simply `echo "Bcc: one@example.net, two@example.org"` in between the other `echo`s would work fine.