# How to forward spam to SpamCop.net with procmail

Tags: procmail, spamassassin

From https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail

---

```
:0fw
| /usr/bin/spamassassin

:0H
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
/dev/null

:0H:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
./Spam
```

---

I would like to complement the move to /dev/null with a forward to submit.[id]@spam.spamcop.net.

I have only found simple forwarding as an action (!). But Spamcop also needs the headers, so I would have to create an empty email with the email as attachment.

```
{
    :0 c
    ! submit.[id]@spam.spamcop.net

    :0
    /dev/null
}
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709669/using-procmail-to-forward-inline

Comment: @tripleee I don't think so: Inline != as MIME attachment

Comment: But it is; just set `Content-type: message/rfc822` in the container message.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks. I added this to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using spamassasin/spamc for sending spam reports via SMTP to spamcop.net? See `Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::SpamCop` and `--reporttype` command line option of spamc. It would require confirmation via WWW unless you use "quick" spamcop reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Procmail has no built-in mechanism to forward as attachment. However, a simple shell script does the trick. In fact, spamcop.net offers a [simple Perl script](https://www.spamcop.net/reporter.pl) for exactly this purpose.

Download this script, edit in your eMail addresses and make it executable, let's say as `$HOME/bin/reporter.pl`.

Then, in your `.procmailrc` use the action `|` ("pipe" or "filter") instead of `!` ("forward"). For instance:

```
:0fw
| /usr/bin/spamassassin

:0w
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
| $HOME/bin/reporter.pl

:0H:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
./Spam
```

Note that the 2nd recipe does not use the flag "f" (filter). With "f" procmail would expect the script to return a message at stdout. That's the case e.g. with "|spamassassin", but our "|reporter.pl" is a so-called delivering recipe. It should not create any output. Hence, `/dev/null` is not needed.

**Edit**

As [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76559027/196133#comment135021114_76559027) messages can also be [forwarded "inline"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26710007/196133), and SpamCop.net is accepting and processing this format apparently just fine. So, adapting tripleee's code the recipe could be

```
:0fw
| /usr/bin/spamassassin

:0w
* ^X-Spam-Level: \*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
| (echo "From: me@example.com"; echo "To: submit.[id]@spam.spamcop.net"; \
   echo "Subject: report spam"; echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"; \
   echo "Content-type: message/rfc822"; echo; cat -) | $SENDMAIL -t

:0H:
* ^X-Spam-Status: Yes
./Spam
```